# Add Header and footer to richtextbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am currently working with richtextbox based [content editor](http://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com) .This is a very good editor but lacks header and footer functionality So bottom line,I want to add header and footer to this content editor.

I have searched in the net regarding header and footer but they were adding header and footer during printing.

So how can I add header and footer to the richtextbox content editor?

Any links, suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/basic-building/editing-questions/rich-text-editor

According to this, the header and footer functionality should be in the Advanced tab of the Look and Feel section.

Comment: @jamieHennerly thanks for ur response but sorry you are reffering to some other link and not the  content editor i am talking about.

Header footer functionality is not present in the this richtextEditor anyways thanks for ur help!!!!!!!11